# How do you insert HTML into a QuillJS?

Tags: javascript, html, quill

Is it possible to insert raw HTML into a Quill? I've been searching the documentation but couldn't find anything.

If it's not possible, can I at least convert HTML into a Quill Delta?

The reason I need this is because I am grabbing the raw HTML of the text taken from Quill, so I can view it later in HTML style. Have I been doing everything wrong, and need to keep a Delta version of it as well?

Answer (score 71):

On version 1.3.6,
You can use `Quill.setContents(value)` method.

And insert your new HTML like this:

```
const value = `<h1>New content here</h1>`
const delta = quill.clipboard.convert(value)

quill.setContents(delta, 'silent')
```

Quill documentation: https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#setcontents

Comment: You mean 1.3.6. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `convert()` isn't documented at https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/
Should `dangerouslyPasteHTML` be used instead?

Comment: This is a much better all-around solution than setting `quill.root.innerHTML`. When you don't convert it to a delta, the inner text will become corrupt if there's any special characters for one thing.

Comment: Also if you are using quill 2.0 `quill.clipboard.convert` the parameter is destructured as `{html, text}` so in this example you would need to use `quill.clipboard.convert({html: value})` or the result will be an empty delta.

Comment: BEWARE - the convert() function is not documented on purpose and may be susceptible to XSS, read thread here https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/3364

Comment: For me, this sets the html tags as text. Any idea why?

Answer (score 47):

I have found a way, looking extremely closely at the documentation. Method `quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML('raw html');` does the trick. https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/#dangerouslypastehtml

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Directly setting the innerHTML or `.html()` with jQuery was causing the Quill editor to re-format and change some of the HTML that we were passing in. This method worked for us.

Comment: For me it shows the tags as text. Any idea why?

Answer (score 5):

Another way to insert HTML into Quill is by using vanilla JavaScript.

You can set your html to a variable, such as `htmlToInsert`.

Then target the `contenteditable` div created by Quill, by getting it by its class, `ql-editor`.

Finally, set the `innerHTML` of that div to the HTML you want to insert.

For example:

```
var htmlToInsert = "<p>here is some <strong>awesome</strong> text</p>"
var editor = document.getElementsByClassName('ql-editor')
editor[0].innerHTML = htmlToInsert
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the most straight forward way is this:

```
quill.root.innerHTML = '<p>HTML Goes Here</p>'
```

You can also obtain the HTML from this property as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is better way to do this:

```
const htmlMurkup = '<p>Good</p>'
let quill = new Quill()
quill.container.firstChild.innerHTML = htmlMurkup
```

Comment: You should definitely use Quill's API when performing operations like this.

Comment: Technically setting innerHTML works. And the Quill will fire a text-change event. But you can not control what the `source` value is. And therefore it will be difficult to reliably set (or not set) a dirty flag or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't getting the desired output. It could be because your html content is encoded.

Use this to convert it.

```js
let realHTML = $('<textarea />').html("&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Hello&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;").text();
console.log(realHTML);
```

This code will output

```html
<p><strong>Hello</strong></p>
```

After this you can use this command to set the html content in quill editor

```js
quill.root.innerHTML = realHTML;
```

or even this:

```js
let initialContent = quill.clipboard.convert(realHTML);
quill.setContents(initialContent, 'silent');
```

**Its proper your html is in the real html format before setting the value on quill. Else the html tags would be displayed verbally.**

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to [@user1993629's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46627801/10885621), using `quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHtml(0, "raw  html")` will place the cursor at the end of the pasted content