# quote a reply with quill editor

Tags: javascript, html, quill, vue-quill-editor

I'm building a forum app and i want to be able to quote a reply.

I'm trying to figure out of there is a way to include in a blockquote any type of html that that might be included in a reply.

For example

Let's say that there is a reply with the following body

```
<h1> Title of reply </h1>
<ul> 
 <li> first item </>
</ul>
```

Therefore i want to be able to quote the above body as it is.

Currently, i've noticed that when i try to insert a block level html tag  into a blockquote in quill editor
like

```
var editor = document.querySelector('ql-editor');
editor.innerHTML = <h1> some random text </h1>
```

The quill editor doesn't display it.
Probably it is rejected and it only accepts inline elements

Comment: Hello, may I ask if you have found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

As answered in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61482805/2637098), you can use the clipboard to convert HTML to a Delta.

Follow up your `setContents` with a `formatText` to convert it to a quote. Documentation for Quill formatText: https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#formattext

A complete example could work like this.

```js
const html = document.querySelector('post-number-342').innerHTML;
const delta = quill.clipboard.convert(html);
quill.setContents(delta, 'silent');
quill.formatText(0, quill.getLength(), 'blockquote', true, 'silent');
```