# Return HTML to QuillJS

Tags: javascript, html

I want to return HTML to QuillJS editor.

It works this way:

```
var htmlToInsert = "<p>Line 1</p><p><br></p><p><strong>Bold line 2</strong></p>";
var editor = document.getElementsByClassName('ql-editor');
editor[0].innerHTML = htmlToInsert;
```

[proper rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytrm7.png)

When I get the inner HTML from a textarea, Quill renders the full HTML markup:

```
var htmlToInsert = $('#textarea').html();
var editor = document.getElementsByClassName('ql-editor');
editor[0].innerHTML = htmlToInsert;
```

[unwanted, full HTML markup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5rRB.png)

What am I doing wrong in scenario 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code snippet works on me

```html
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="editor">
</div>
<textarea id="textarea"><p>Line 1</p><p><br></p><p><strong>Bold line 2</strong></p></textarea>
<button onclick="run()">Run</button>
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<script>
  var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
      theme: 'snow'
  });
  function run(){
      var htmlToInsert = 
      document.querySelector("#textarea").value;
      var editor = document.querySelector('#editor');
      editor.innerHTML = htmlToInsert;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: unfortunately, this is still not working (I thought it worked but it was just caching). Still displays the full HTML markup in my case :(

Comment: @spacerabbit can you edit the question with including not working code snipped ?

Comment: I tried it like this now, as proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46627801/12834237
Still the same bad result.



`var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic'],
      [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
    ]
  },
  theme: 'snow'  
});

var htmlToInsert = document.querySelector("#div_hidden").innerHTML;
quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(htmlToInsert);
`

Comment: that code is working on my browser https://jsfiddle.net/1kdsa9vo/1/
what browser are you using ?

Comment: thanks for your support. I didn't mention that I grab from a textarea, now changed the question. Didn't think this could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs when grabbing the inner HTML from a textarea. I now grab it from an input field value, which works. It needs to be a form element as I need to be capable to post the data.